# Show a company profile page using a referance table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am somewhat new to C# and MVC Razor pages. I want to show a company profile page to the logged in user which is a member of that Company. I have 3 tables for this view UsersToAddresses, CustomerNames, and Addresses. The usersToAddresses gets the UserId automatically inserted by a trigger in SQL when a user registers. This table only has 2 columns UserId and AddressId. I did this because more than one user can be a member of a company and I did not want to store duplicate data. In SQL UsersToAddresses.AddressId is linked to Addresses.AddressId by foreign key. CustomerNames.CustomerId is linked to Addresses.CustomerId by foreign Key. I want to be able to show on the user Dashboard the Company Name with a list of addresses for that company. They may only have one address. I am assuming that creating a ViewModel is the best way to do this, I have a viewModel created for the page. I also have the userId as an extension of the link. So it would be Http:localhost:3125/customers/fdsa531as654few44231431fdvafbfzs
[EDIT] After much discussion with @Marcelo Myara I have finally got this to work they way I want it to. Below I will show the changes marked with [EDIT]. Below code is fully functional and works as expected.

Controller:

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "CompanyAdmin")]
    public ActionResult Index(string UserId)
    {
        if (UserId == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
   [EDIT] - "Changed to use modelInstance"
        //Trying to get a view model for customer from the received UserId.
        CompanyOverview modelInstance = CompanyOverview.GetCompanyByUser(UserId, db);
        if (modelInstance == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(modelInstance);

        // Addresses userAddress = db.Addresses.Find(UserId);
        // if (userAddress == null)
        // {
        //    return HttpNotFound();
        // }
        // return View(userAddress);
    }
```

Basically a copy of the Details in the controller, but this uses a db.Addresses and I am not using that in the view. I am using a ViewModel.

Here is my view Model:

```
    public partial class CompanyOverview
{
    public CompanyOverview()
    [EDIT] - "Not used"
    //{
    //    AddressDetail = new List<Addresses>();
    //}
    [EDIT] - "Not Needed"
    // [Key]

    [Edit] - "Added proper joins for use of referance table"
            //Static method to get an instance of your model when given an userId and DbContext instance.
    public static CompanyOverview GetCompanyByUser(string userId, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var qCus = from ad in db.Addresses
                   join ua in db.UserToAddresses on ad.AddressId equals ua.AddressId
                   join cus in db.CustomerNames on ad.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                   where (ua.UserId == userId)
                   select new CompanyOverview()
                   {
                       UserId = userId,
                       AddressId = ad.AddressId,
                       Customer = cus.CustomerName,
                       CustomerName = cus,
                       Location = ad.LocationName,
                       Addresses = ad
                   };


        var result = qCus.SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerId == result.CustomerName.CustomerId);
        };
        return result;
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    [EDIT] - "Added for use on page if needed - Customer allows me to show the company name at the top of the razor page"
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerNames CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Addresses> AddressDetail { get; set; }
}
```

This might not be correct either. So as a result I have to find the UserId in the UsersToAddresses table and have it pull the addresses from the addresses table that match the UserId. If someone can help with this it would be appreciated. Thank You.

Updated Nov 8th 2018 - added table Definitions.

UsersToAddresses:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersToAddresses](
[UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[AddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersToAddresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY= OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON
[PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersToAddresses]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT
[FK_dbo.UsersToAddresses_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersToAddresses] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_dbo.UsersToAddresses_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

Customers Table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerNames](
[CustomerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NOT NULL,
[Terms] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[TaxCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CustomerNames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CustomerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerNames] ADD  CONSTRAINT
[DF_CustomerNames_Status]
DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Status]
GO
```

Addresses Table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses](
[AddressId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Status] [bit] NULL,
[IsBilling] [bit] NULL,
[IsShipping] [bit] NULL,
[ContactName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Line1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Line2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ZipCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FaxNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastUpdated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CustomerId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[AddressId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Addresses_LastUpdated]
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [LastUpdated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT
[FK_Addresses_CustomerNames] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomerNames] ([CustomerId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] CHECK CONSTRAINT
[FK_Addresses_CustomerNames]
GO
```

Update Nov 10 2018 - Added RazorView

RazorView:

```
@model BestenEquipment.Models.CompanyOverview

@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateProfile";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/CustomerDashboardLayout.cshtml";
}


<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>CompanyOverview</h2>
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer)</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        Company Addresses:
    [EDIT] - "Added Table for headers"
                    <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.Status)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.LocationName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.ContactName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.EmailAddress)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.Line1)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.Line2)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.IsBilling)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.IsShipping)
                </th>
            </tr>
    [EDIT] - "Corrected the foreach statement"
          //  @foreach (var item in Model.AddressDetail)
          //  {
          //  <dd> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)</dd>
          //  }
              @foreach (var item in Model.AddressDetail)
                {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Line1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Line2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsBilling)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsShipping)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UserEdit", "Addresses", new { id = item.AddressId }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Addresses", new { id = item.AddressId }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
            </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
</div>
```

So there you have it. I will be adding encryption to the AddressId so that the user cannot change the number and view other customers records.

Comment: Can you include the tables definitions on you question? That would help a lot in understanding your goal.

Comment: @MarceloMyara added the Tables. Your help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding, you will only have one Address associated with a user at a time. First, you want to get the AddressID associated with the current user on the `UsersToAddresses` table. Then you want to load your model (`CompanyOverview`) with the one Customer associated with that one AddressID that you got on the first place, plus all the Addresses associated with that Customer, does it sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to address directly your question (although there's a lot of things that could be learned and improved here). So:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "CompanyAdmin")]
public ActionResult Index(string UserId)
{
    if (UserId == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    //Trying to get a view model for customer from the received UserId.
    CompanyOverview modelInstance = CompanyOverview.GetCompanyByUser(UserId, db);
    if (modelInstance == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    } 
    return View(modelInstance);
}

//From your question I'm taking this class as a ViewModel only
public partial class CompanyOverview
{
    //Keeping it here just because you implemented it (if not used elsewhere, just remove this)
    public CompanyOverview()
    {
        AddressDetail = new List<Addresses>();
    }

    //Static method to get an instance of your model when given an userId and DbContext instance. Correct the DbContext type name in the below parameter.
    public static CompanyOverview GetCompanyByUser(int userId, YourDbContext db)
    {
        var qCus = from ad in db.Addresses
                      join ua in db.UsersToAddresses on ad.AddressID equals ua.AddressId
                      join cus in db.CustomerNames on ua.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                      where (ua.UserId == userId)
                      select new CompanyOverview() {
                          UserId = userId,
                          AddressId = ad.AddressId,
                          CustomerName = cus
                      };

        var result = qCus.SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null) 
        {
            result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerId == result.CustomerName.CustomerId)
        }
        return result;
    }

    //[Key] <- You don't need to define a Key annotation, since this will only be a ViewModel (thus, not having persistence by EF).
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerNames CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Addresses> AddressDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Check if that help you in any way... (I'm still not sure if I got you right and as I said before, there are lots of things to improve here - but I'm trying to address your specific question and using your type of solution only, to make sure I'll not confuse you).

Comment: Thank you for your help, a few things. This line join ua in db.UsersToAddresses on ad.AddressID equals ad.AddressId I am getting an error that is "The name 'ad' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals' " And this line " result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a. CustomerId == c.CustomerId)
" I am getting an error "The c does not exit in the current context" this is the last c.CustomerId

Comment: Switching things around I now have only I error and that is the c.CustomerId

Comment: I commented the address.where out just to run it to see what it produced. Im my view I have @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerName) which produces all the columns in the CustomerName table I only want to display the CustomerName. and addresses related to the company.

Comment: So I fixed the seeing the name only. I added  public string Customer { get; set; } and Changed CustomerName = cus to Customer = cus,CustomerName. Now it only displays the customer name. Still need to figure out the Address part though.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the mistakes... Just edited my answer with the corrections. Just so you know: 1st-> `join ua in db.UsersToAddresses on ad.AddressID equals ua.AddressId` since to make that join we want the value on UserToAddresses (ua) to be equal the value on Addresses (ad); 2nd-> `result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerId == result.CustomerId)` since we want all addresses that has the value on CustomerId equal the value present on the object that we got from the previous query (which is present in `result`).

Comment: So I am now getting 'CompanyOverview' does not contain a definition for 'CustomerId' and no extention method 'CustomerId' accepting a first argument of type 'ConpanyOverview' could be found. this is for the result.CustomerId. Also in my view what do I put in it to produce the List of addresses?

Comment: My bad again. I meant: `result.AddressDetail = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerId == result.CustomerName.CustomerId)`.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you show some code to put in the view to produce the Addresses. I tried using  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddressDetail) but just got a long string showing this... System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerNames_C4CD6768B409F80E7ACC77A793F399D15655623E00F916DDBEE381C7570D2058System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.CustomerNames_C4CD6768B409F80E7ACC77A793F399D15655623E00F916DDBEE381C7570D2058

Comment: I had to change a few things with entities because it was giving be grief. I also changed ICollection<Addresses> AddressDetail to IQueryable<Addresses> AddressDetail because it did not like the ICollection due to the entities being different. I also added public string Location {get; set;} and added it in the result. I did a foreach in my view and it supplies 2 (duplicate) LocationNames instead of the 2 that exist for this record. So 2 address records have the same CustomerId and only the 1 shows twice. I added the view to the top with the rest of my code.

Comment: So I believe this solution will work for the Company users that will be added and connected to the locations. but for the CompanyAdmin I would like to show all addresses of the company. Users will be assigned to addresses by CompanyAdmin. So this view should show all addresses related to the company. CompanyUser will get a different page with only the address they are associated with. The problem with this I believe is the SingleOrDefault(); So naturally it will only return 1. I hope this clears up the confusion. Thanks

Comment: Your concerns are a little bit too broad for this kind of forum. If you really want to get most of Stack Overflow you have to research by yourself and then ask for help on specific and closed scope questions. So, I'll just point you in the direction I do think will be easier for you to learn (and research) the most by yourself: The model is an Object, with it's properties (that can be simple typed, like int or string, or complex type like a class or a list - which is a class also).

Comment: The view is HTML + razor (a language that aloows you to manipulate the model or use C# statements in order to generate HTML). The objective is to end up with HTML for the resulting page (the model hold some of the data that you want to use on that HTML). At your level, imao, you should be constructing the HTML manually (instead of using helpers). You should think in terms of `<input type="text" value="@Model.CustomerName.CustomerName" />` or `@foreach (var A in Model.AddressDetail) { <div class="myFormattedField">@A.Line1</div> }` (with the proper line breaks after and before brackets).

Comment: See if that helps you undestand what you're doing in every step. Find a tutorial close to what you're trying to do and follow it through. When needed, come back with specific questions and specific problems that can be answered directly. Good luck.

Comment: After fully undestanding how to manually construct the HTML that you want, then I'll be ready to take advantage on shortcut provided by helpers (that are, in fact, simple C# functions that construct the HTML using the provided parameters), allowing you to write less, be less repetitive and still fully undertand what to expect on the resulting generated page.

Comment: I do know how to construct with Html etc, The issue was that the code that you provided only returns 1 record of addresses. I did the foreach but in comes back with 2 duplicate records. When there are 2 different address records for the Company. I have been researching the SingleorDefault and FirstOrDefaut and I appears that neither of them will work as I need to produce all address records that belong to the Company.

Comment: The ICollection does not work because it represents a generic list and the Addresses model entity is not. The entity is set to be IDbSet which should work with ICollection or IList but I got an error that it  Cannot convert type system.Linq.IQueryable to Systems.Collections.Generic.ICollection. It seems that there are not very many cases where a referance table is used. I did research and maybe I am asking the wrong thing, but I did not find much. Thanks again for your help. Your code will work for the other users, because I only need it to produce 1 record. In this case I need all.

Comment: So as it turns out. I went back through my code. I did have the foreach wrong. That was my bad... It is working now! Again thank you for your help. I would like to update my code on here as for myself, I hate seeing partial code when looking for something. Should I post a new post or Just correct what I have up here? My code is a little different than what you have but not by much.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean to do with Address now (it's still not fully clear to me what your entities represent). So, just to clarify: `SingleOrDefault()` as the name suggests, will pick 1 or 0 instances (default being null in that case); `FirstOrDefault` will pick the first instance (when at least one is available) or null (being the default in your case); `ToList()` will return a list of the query's returned type, containing all results from it (that's what you're looking for, right?)

Comment: If you want to update your question with the new code, people usually edit the question and place a new session beggining with "EDIT:" (and explaining what changed and why). Other option is to answer your own question.

Comment: I fixed my foreach code and now it is coming up with both records. They happen  to be the only 2 records in the table right now. I thought I changed the SingleOrDefault to FirstOrDefault and I did not. So maybe my ForEach is grabbing all records. I will verify that and then update the top. My foreach is currently  @foreach (var item in Model.AddressDetail). Which would make me think at this point it is not even using the code for the SingleOrDefault, it is going straight through the IQueryable. So I guess I have to figure a few things out. 1 being how to do the foreach using the code.

Comment: And 2 how to get more than 1 record to display. I think the FirstOrDefault may be the answer to that.

Comment: I continue to fail to fully understand your models. But if you're using the `CompanyOverview` instance as returned by `GetCompanyByUser(...)`, you will have a customer (only one), represented in that instace, and all the Addresses linked to it on the property `Model.AddressDetail`. So, just for your understanding: In my code, I used the `var result = qCus.SingleOrDefault();` to get one (and only one) CompanyOverview instance. Inside it, it will have a list of addresses on the AddressDetail property.

Comment: So this is getting lengthy in the comments and I am sure someone is going to bark soon. However I have confirmed that my Foreach is only listing addresses that belong to the customer. Even though the result is a SingleOrDefault. It is working the way I want it to right now. So there is no need to change anything on this. Thanks again for the help. Also I have another question posted on encryption if you would like to look at that and give it a stab... [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269256/encryption-using-crypto-in-mvc-asp-net-on-id-only[/link]